# Toast message not showed and following code ignored

Tags: android, inner-classes, toast, android-context

I have the following code:

```
protected MyCallback getMyCallbackHandler() {
    return new MyCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onReady() {
            // DO STUFF
            if (stuff!= null) {
                mThread = new MyThread(stuff,MyActivity.this);
                mThread.execute(mSensors.getLocation());
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "No target detected! Try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mSensors.registerCallback(null);
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() { 
                    comp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            });
        }
    };
}
```

The problem is that if `stuff==null` when `Toast.makeText(...).show()`is called, first the toast message doesn't appear and second the next lines seems to be not executed.
If I comment just the `Toast`line, everything run as expected.

I tried to put as context `MyActivity.this`, `getParent().getApplicationContext()`and also `getApplicationContext()`but it doesn't work.

Comment: put the `Toast` in a try catch block and print the exception in the logcat

Comment: Oh yes you are right. I'm trying.

Comment: the exception throwed `07-14 19:24:01.777: W/System.err(32619): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to make the call to Toast on the main UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

you can't use `Toast` here you should use `Log.d()` , if you really want to debug the applications start playing with Logcat !

if you want to use Toast inside this pass context to `getMyCallbackHandler(Context c)`

and use that in your Toast like

```
else {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(c, "No target detected! Try again later.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            });
            mSensors.registerCallback(null);
        }
```

Comment: I always play with logcat but please, you have to be more clear. I can't use Toast? ok but why?

Comment: It would be great but I'm using an SDK that doesn't pass to me the Context. Yatin is right